# Multiple for-each loops in Hadoop reducer

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I faced the problem of multiple for-each loops in Hadoop, is it even possible?

What code I have now for reducer class:

```
public class R_PreprocessAllSMS extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text>{
private final static Text KEY = new Text();
private final static Text VALUE = new Text();

    @Override
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int sum = 0;
        for (Text value : values) {
            String[] splitString = value.toString().split("\t");
            sum += Integer.parseInt(splitString[1]);
        }
        if (sum > 100) {
            for (Text value : values) {
                String[] splitString = value.toString().split("\t");
                System.out.println(key.toString() + splitString[0] + " " + splitString[1]);
                KEY.set(key);
                VALUE.set(splitString[0] + "\t" + splitString[1]);
                context.write(KEY, VALUE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I want to have a possibility to search through given values for the second time and to emit those which we need. If it's not possible, what is the recommended way of doing that in Hadoop you'd advice?
Thanks.

Comment: I think what you are doing is right. mapreduce api doesnot provide additional functionality to do multiple for each loops.Reducer is not a heavy task so it is not much of a headache if you add multiple for loops

Comment: the better question is why your reducer is getting a list of tab delimited lines as input...what is your mapper doing??

Comment: Well, that's just an example of what I'd like to do with my reducer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of looping twice you can delay writing the values until you know that the sum is high enough, something like:

```
    int sum = 0;
    List list = new ArrayList<String>();
    KEY.set(key);

    for (Text value : values) {
        String[] splitString = value.toString().split("\t");
        String line = splitString[0] + "\t" + splitString[1];

        sum += Integer.parseInt(splitString[1]);

        if (sum < 100) {
            list.add(line);
        } else {
            if (!list.isEmpty()) {
                for (String val: list) {
                   VALUE.set(val);
                   context.write(KEY, VALUE);
                }
                list.clear();
            }
            VALUE.set(line);
            context.write(KEY, VALUE);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use two pair of Mappres and Reducers? You can call them one after another.
For example create two jobs in one main. Second get results of first.

```
JobConf jobConf1 = new JobConf();  
JobConf jobConf2 = new JobConf();  

Job job1 = new Job(jobConf1);  

Job job2 = new Job(jobConf2);
```

Or tou can look on that:http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/ChainReducer.html

Comment: Well, that's the most obvious way to do it, always do the job that way, but I'm really interested is there any major advantages in new API that allows for-each loops?